# how to add post id number to image name in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new in php. I am building a website with laravel. I want to add post number to image which upload when post created,

My Store controller:

```
public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Post::$rules);

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $post = new Post;
            $post->title = Input::get('title');
            $post->body = Input::get('body');
            $post->reporter = Input::get('reporter');
            $post->meta = Input::get('meta');
            $post->slug = Input::get('title');
            $post->top = Input::get('top');
            $post->pubdate = Input::get('pubdate');

            $image = Input::file('image');
            if ($image) {
                $filename = "image274".$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(250, 145)->save('public/images/postimages/'.$filename);
                $post->image = 'images/postimages/'.$filename;
            }


            $categories = Input::get('categories');

            $post->save();

            $post->categories()->sync($categories);

             return Redirect::route('admin.posts.index')
                ->with('message', 'Product Created');
        }

        return Redirect::back()
            ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
```

Is it possible? Please help me.

Thanks
Saiful

Comment: in $filename variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to first save the post to DB, then get the currently saved post id and then only you can add the post id to the image filename.

Something like following code might work:

```
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Post::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = Input::get('title');
        $post->body = Input::get('body');
        $post->reporter = Input::get('reporter');
        $post->meta = Input::get('meta');
        $post->slug = Input::get('title');
        $post->top = Input::get('top');
        $post->pubdate = Input::get('pubdate');

        $post->save();

        $image = Input::file('image');
        if ($image) {
            $filename = "image274".$post->id.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(250, 145)->save('public/images/postimages/'.$filename);
            $post->image = 'images/postimages/'.$filename;
            $post->save();
        }


        $categories = Input::get('categories');

        $post->categories()->sync($categories);

         return Redirect::route('admin.posts.index')
            ->with('message', 'Product Created');
    }

    return Redirect::back()
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```